# javascript to remove \x22 in Google Tag Manager

Tags: javascript

I have the following javascript to get the h1 element on a page:

```
function() {
var name=document.querySelector('h1').textContent;  
return name;
}
```

It works fine, but where i have double quotes on the value of a h1 it outputs a backslash followed by x22:

```
\x22
```

For example:

```
<h1>5" Boning Knife</h1>
```

Would return this: 5\x22 Boning Knife

But i need this: 5 Boning Knife

How do i make it so it doesn't output any double quotes if they exist in a h1 name?

Comment: I wasn't able to reproduce the 5\x22 (mine showed "5'' Boning Knife"). Can you check this and confirm what you still need it to do? https://jsfiddle.net/6pxb6zbk/

Answer (score 0):

Got it:

```
function() {

var element=document.querySelector('h1').textContent;

var name = element.replace(/"/g,"");

return name;

}
```